# Ubuntu stuck on loading screen "snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudio00: vmaster hook already present before ci dev" and Dependency failed for /mnt/--uuid--

Tags: boot, dual-boot, fstab

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dual boot with Windows 10

Hp Studio G5 x360

Newbie here. I have been struggling with this problem for two days now. When I try to boot Ubuntu I get the following message:

`snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudio00: vmaster hook already present before ci dev

[Time] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/--uuid--

[Depend] Dependency failed for /mnt/-- same uuid--`

I have tried to fix the problem in a couple of ways. I ran boot-repair-disk which didn't fix the problem. I also managed to open my fstab from a live-usb however some small edits that I tried to do didn't work out. Here is my fstab:
[My fstab the second to last line was commented out by me which removed the last two lines of the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3fAn.jpg)

Except for commenting out the line, I also tried replacing the --uuid-- with the uuid of my Linux partition. This also didn't work out.

I will also include an image of my blkid:
[My blikid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYPkg.jpg)

Finally, this is my error log:
[The full error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu4T2.jpg)

I am sorry for the phone images but this is the only way I can take any.

Thank you in advance for the help